# Manually set transport type on a Spring + Sockjs application

Tags: java, spring, long-polling, spring-websocket, sockjs

I need to install an application on a non JEE7 compliant server. I am using Spring + Stomp + SocksJs for realtime notifications.

My code looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry ser) {
        ser.addEndpoint("/notifications").withSockJS()
    }

   }

}
```

And on the client:

```
function setSocket(broker, callbackFn) {

    var socket = {};

    socket.cliente = new SockJS(path + broker);
    socket.stomp = Stomp.over(socket.cliente);

    socket.stomp.connect({}, function () {
        socket.stomp.subscribe("/topic" + broker, callbackFn);
    });

}
```

Is there any way to manually set the transport type to use and avoid the use of websockets?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your server doesn't support websockets, make sure that it still support async handling.

You can disable the websocket transport on the server side with the following option:

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry ser) {
    ser.addEndpoint("/notifications").withSockJS().setWebSocketEnabled(false);
}
```

SockJS clients will automatically select the best available transport supported by the server. In your case, this is the preferred way to deal with this.

As explained in the [SockJS client documentation](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client#sockjs-client-api), you can limit the available transports on the client side with a `transports` argument when creating the SockJS client.

```
sockJsProtocols = ["xhr-streaming", "xhr-polling"];
socket.cliente = new SockJS(url, null, {transports: sockJsProtocols});
```

The full [list of available transports is here](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client#supported-transports-by-browser-html-served-from-http-or-https). But technically, if you're not restricting the available transports on the server side, a client could still attempt to connect using websockets.

Comment: Thank u! that was exactly what I needed.

Comment: I've edited my answer - in your case, you want to restrict the available transports *on the server side*. Doing so just on the client works, but does not prevent a client to try connecting to your server with websockets, if that client is configured otherwise.

Comment: I've stopped manually the server, after couple of minutes again i've started server, client shows the message like Opening Web Socket..., not connecting websocket